Need datasheet/pinout for CD1450C module
I am currently working with a DC-DC converter labeled as CD1450C. We have industrial power supply that has this component. Dimension is 50x50 mm. But I am unable to find its datasheet or detailed specifications. Could anyone please provide the datasheet, pinout, or any related documentation?


Please edit the question and add a picture of the bottom of the device. Please also measure the external dimensions with a caliper and include them in the question. This will help with finding it.

From the industrial power supply to which the CD1450C was fitted, is there any indication of the input / output voltages and currents for the module?

It's an obsolete part. Contact Murata support

@ChesterGillon No. the one that I have isn't working so we need to replace with an equivalent one.

It looks like a custom part no. the only way to obtain any information is through murata

@Jeroen3 I've tried contacting Murata but unfortunately no response from their side yet

Date code is 1718  yyww
It's an obsolete part. Contact Murata support
Update 2440 yyww
eBay has surplus parts now in Shenzhen.
Then record Vin, Vout for future replacement and tag the part.  This InOut is often part of the style number.

I've tried contacting Murata but unfortunately no response from their side yet
